# How do you use vi (or another editor) as part of another command to edit something and return it to that command?

Tags: python, linux

For example, if you have ever used git, when you do a commit it will open vi to add or edit some text, and when you exit it is able to intercept this and use that text.  What is this called so I can lookup some docs on it?  Any other information, especially performing this using python, would be very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Often, the user's `$EDITOR` environment variable is executed, and instructed to write a temporary file with some random name.  The temporary file can then be read back in by your application and discarded when no longer needed.

```
# Your application makes a system call like:
$EDITOR /tmp/randfile1124098weasc9839x.txt
```

This allows the text editor to be a user preference.  `$EDITOR` could be `/usr/bin/vi`, `/usr/bin/emacs`, whatever.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how you can do this with Python:

```
import tempfile, os

f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
os.system("vi " + f.name) # this will open vi to edit your temporary file
text = f.read()
```

Answer (score 2):

All you are doing is making a system call to a file in a temp directory.  When the system call returns, read the file.